# Adding spaces in c#

Tags: c#

Is there a more proficient way to add spaces to the output?

```
//define variables
string myName;
int myAge;

//input
Console.Write("Enter Name:");
myName = (Console.ReadLine());
Console.Write("Enter Age:");
myAge = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

//output
Console.Write("Hello" + " " + myName + " " + "Your age is" + " " + myAge);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: `String.Format` or string interpolation in C#6.

Comment: why not `Console.Write("Hello "+ myName + " Your age is " +  myAge);`?

Comment: You can do it using interpolated strings. Looks much nicer. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`String.Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx)

Example:

```
String.Join(" ", "Hello", myName, "Your age is", myAge);
```

Note: Since you asked about adding white spaces this would be the way, however I highly recommend you to use string interpolation (c# 6) or string formatting via `String.Format`

Comment: @abelenky you are absolutely wrong, String.Join takes params string[] values (in one of four overloads). Please read about params keyword on the https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx

Comment: Apparently not absolutely wrong, just old-school.  the `params` wasn't added until .Net 4.0.  From versions 3.5 and earlier, it was `(String, String[])`, only.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use C# 6? Then use string interpolation. Is much more elegant.

Example:

`"Hello" + " " + myName + " " + "Your age is" + " " + myAge`

becomes

`$"Hello {myName} Your age is {myAge}"`

Comment: I could use c#6 but as I am taking a Tafe course in Programming basics c# is what I have to use for now. I will read into string interpolation though. Thanks.

Comment: @Shmaves Well, string interpolation is just syntax sugar for `string.Format()` so it will be good for you to understand where it came for. Keep up the good work.